# MediaCodec.createInputSurface() throws IllegalStateException in Android emulator (Error -38)

Tags: java, android, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I have `MediaMuxer`:

```
MediaMuxer mMediaMuxer = new MediaMuxer(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "video.mp4").getPath(), MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
```

And code, which records video:

```
MediaFormat mMediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", width, height);
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 128000);
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, fps);
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 10);
MediaCodec mMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
mMediaCodec.configure(mMediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
Surface mSurface = mMediaCodec.createInputSurface();
...
```

Last string `mMediaCodec.createInputSurface()`, throws me `java.lang.IllegalStateException`. Stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaCodec.createInputSurface(Native Method)
    at com.mypackage.Cam$Recorder$VideoRecorder.run(Cam.java:307)
```

And logs of emulator:

```
02-05 07:42:55.024: I/OMXClient(2643): Using client-side OMX mux.
02-05 07:42:55.024: I/SoftAVCEncoder(2643): Construct SoftAVCEncoder
02-05 07:42:55.024: E/SoftAVCEncoder(2643): internalSetParameter: StoreMetadataInBuffersParams.nPortIndex not zero!
02-05 07:42:55.024: E/OMXNodeInstance(2643): OMX_SetParameter() failed for StoreMetaDataInBuffers: 0x80001001
02-05 07:42:55.024: E/ACodec(2643): [OMX.google.h264.encoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers (output) failed w/ err -2147483648
02-05 07:42:55.024: I/ACodec(2643): setupVideoEncoder succeeded
02-05 07:42:55.024: E/OMXNodeInstance(2643): createInputSurface requires COLOR_FormatSurface (AndroidOpaque) color format
02-05 07:42:55.024: E/ACodec(2643): [OMX.google.h264.encoder] onCreateInputSurface returning error -38
02-05 07:42:55.024: W/MediaCodec(2643): createInputSurface failed, err=-38
02-05 07:42:55.024: E/TAG(2643): java.lang.IllegalStateException
02-05 07:42:55.224: I/OMXClient(2643): Using client-side OMX mux.
02-05 07:42:55.254: W/SoftAACEncoder2(2643): Requested bitrate 128000 unsupported, using 48000
```

I observed this string

```
E/OMXNodeInstance(2643): createInputSurface requires COLOR_FormatSurface (AndroidOpaque) color format
```

says my `Surface` must be in `COLOR_FormatSurface`, but I have already set it

```
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
```

What's wrong? How to solve this problem? Help.

Comment: It looks pretty good to me. Try messing around with the bitrate (large range of high and low values) and see if that resolves the error.

Comment: @nyttimangus, what version of Android did you tested? It is strange, but nothing happens when I changing bitrate value.. Still I tried to change *KEY_FRAME_RATE* (fps) and *KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL*. It doesn't help.

Comment: I didn't test your code, but I have tested some of my own work with MediaCodec on API 19 and 23, I believe, but compatible to 18. I just thought I remembered running into a similar issue when I had my bitrate wrong.

Comment: @nyttimangus, what bitrate is supported by all devices (and emulators)?

Comment: I'm really not sure. I ended up going with the Kush gauge for calculating a bitrate as specified at http://www.ezs3.com/public/What_bitrate_should_I_use_when_encoding_my_video_How_do_I_optimize_my_video_for_the_web.cfm

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I think it won't work on emulators : https://github.com/google/grafika/issues/2.
In the AVD I set 'Emulated performance' to 'Hardware', but it didn't solve the problem.
You should try on a real device.
EDIT : well, it seems to work on emulators with API >= 23 (even though your code should run with API 18), but you probably will have to change the directory during your tests, because of : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html